# How do I get index of repeated data from multi dimension array in different variables using array_search() method

Tags: php, arrays, array-column

how to get index of repeated data from a multi dimension array using array_search() or array_column() method

```
function Search($value, $array) 
{ 
return(array_search($value, $array,false)); 
}
$array = array(45, 5, 1, 22, 22, 10, 10); 
$value = "10"; 
$index1= Search($value, $array);
echo $index1;
```

this displays index of first '10' from array. How do I get index of 2nd 10 from the array in $index2 varaible. Please help this will help me a lot.

Comment: If needle is found in haystack more than once, the first matching key is returned. To return the keys for all matching values, use `array_keys()` with the optional search_value parameter instead. [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is described in [`array_search` manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#refsect1-function.array-search-returnvalues):

```
function Search($value, $array) 
{ 
    return array_keys($array, $value, false); 
}

$array = array(45, 5, 1, 22, 22, 10, 10); 
$value = "10"; 
$indexes = Search($value, $array);
print_r($indexes);
```

You can see full documentation of `array_keys` [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Answer (score -1):

Use [array_count_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) and [array_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/I9QIe)

```
<?php
$array = array(45, 5, 1, 22, 22, 10, 10); 

//use array_count_values to counts all the values of an array.
$get_repeated_value = array_count_values($array);

$final_array = array();
foreach($get_repeated_value as $key => $value){

    //If value is repeated, get the index of that values from array.
    if($value > 1){
        $final_array[$key] = array_keys($array, $key); 
    }
}


echo "<pre>";
print_r($final_array);

?>
```